# CountVectorizer returns only zeros

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to extract some features from a given document, given a pre-defined set of features.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
features = ['a', 'b', 'c']
doc = ['a', 'c']

vectoriser = CountVectorizer()
vectoriser.vocabulary = features
vectoriser.fit_transform(doc)
```

However the output, is a 2x3 array, filled in with zeros instead of :

```
desired_output = [[1, 0, 0]
                  [0, 0, 1]]
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Does the `doc` represent different samples of data or different features of same sample? If former, then this usage is not suitable for CountVectorizer. You can use [One-hot encoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the default token pattern in CountVectorizer will get rid of any words of only one character long. You can change the default token pattern to fix this:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
features = ['a', 'b', 'c']
doc = ['a', 'c']

vectoriser = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=features, token_pattern=r"\b\w+\b")

vectoriser.fit_transform(doc)
```

Comment: Does the `token_pattern=r"\b\w+\b"` match any token (of any length) ?

Comment: It will capture words with one or more characters, assuming they are in the vocabulary